# How to use Apify SDK to automate selecting a javascript option to crawl a website

Tags: apify

I have read the excellent documentation on using [Apify SDK](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/guides/gettingstarted) to crawl web sites but need a little help as the guide for *PuppeteerCrawler* is not completed

The part of the site I would like to crawl is a members' directory. The main page (which I believe I will need to provide as `RequestList`) contains links to the first 50 members of the directory. To get to the next 50 members, there is an option box which looks like this:

```html
<span id="foo">Show:<select onchange="bar.pagerChanged(this);">
<option value="0">1-50</option>
<option value="50">51-100</option>
<option value="100">101-150</option>
...
<option value="2400">2401-2450</option>
</select>
</span>
```

I'm not sure how I would approach this, except that I think I will need *PuppeteerCrawler* given that user input (clicking on the option with `id="foo"`) is required. What I need to do is to start with the top page, add all 50 links to the `RequestQueue`, then select the next batch of 50 members, and rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly about details of the page but you can select any option with Puppeteer easily like this

```
// First is selector to the select element and second is value of the option
await page.select('#foo select', '50');
```

In some rare cases this doesn't work. Then it can be solved by directly clicking on the select and then one of the displayed elements by simply using

```
await page.click('#foo select');
await page.waitFor(200);
await page.click('selector-for-on-of-the-element-that-popped-up');
```

If there are links inside every option, you can do simple lool

```
const batchSize = 50;
for (let i = 0; i < totalMembers; i += 50) {
    await page.select('#foo select', `${i}`); // i needs to be converted to a string
    const links = extractLinks(); // implement
    for (const url of links) {
        await requestQueue.addRequest({ url });
    }
}
```